# No valid OpenPGP data found when trying to verify signature of .deb package with debsig-verify

Tags: linux, debian, gnupg, slack, deb

### Context

I want to verify the signature of the last version of the slack `.deb` package (`slack-desktop-4.1.2-amd64.deb`), which I downloaded from https://slack.com/intl/en-es/downloads/linux.

I am trying to follow the instructions provided by slack for Debian-based distributions https://slack.com/intl/en-es/help/articles/115004809166-Verify-Slack-for-Linux-(beta)-package-signatures#version-4.1.2-and-above-1 , which use `debsig-verify`.

I am aware of a similar question (same error message from `debsig-verify`, for a different `.deb`) in stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858700/), but what worked for that OP (changing `http` to `https` in the policy file) is not working for me.

### Steps followed

I believe I successfully completed the first steps of the slack-provided instructions:

1. `debsig-verify` correctly installed:

   ```
   # apt-get install debsig-verify
   [...]
   # debsig-verify --version
   Debsig Program Version - 0.18-6-g37b7
     Signature Version - 1.0
     Signature Namespace - https://www.debian.org/debsig/1.0/
     Policies Directory - /etc/debsig/policies
     Keyrings Directory - /usr/share/debsig/keyrings
   ```
2. Slack's public key downloaded:

   ```
   # wget https://slack.com/gpg/slack_pubkey_2019.gpg
   --2019-11-21 17:19:33--  https://slack.com/gpg/slack_pubkey_2019.gpg
   Resolving slack.com (slack.com)... 13.249.2.166
   Connecting to slack.com (slack.com)|13.249.2.166|:443... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
   Length: unspecified [text/plain]
   Saving to: ‘slack_pubkey_2019.gpg’

   slack_pubkey_2019.g     [ <=>                ]   1.63K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

   2019-11-21 17:19:33 (31.7 MB/s) - ‘slack_pubkey_2019.gpg’ saved [1670]
   ```
3. Directories to store debsigs policies and keyrings for Slack's public key created:

   ```
   # mkdir -pv /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/F18462078E6C9578
   mkdir: created directory '/usr/share/debsig/keyrings/F18462078E6C9578'
   # mkdir -pv /etc/debsig/policies/F18462078E6C9578
   mkdir: created directory '/etc/debsig/policies/F18462078E6C9578'
   ```
4. Slack's public key imported into the corresponding debsigs keyring:

   ```
   # gpg --no-default-keyring \
   > --keyring /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/F18462078E6C9578/debsig.gpg \
   > --import slack_pubkey_2019.gpg
   gpg: keybox '/usr/share/debsig/keyrings/F18462078E6C9578/debsig.gpg' created
   gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
   gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
   gpg: key F18462078E6C9578: public key "Slack Packages (Signing Key) <packages@slack-corp.com>" imported
   gpg: Total number processed: 1
   gpg:               imported: 1
   ```

   Content of keyring file checked:

   ```
   # gpg --no-default-keyring \
   > --keyring /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/F18462078E6C9578/debsig.gpg \
   > --check-sigs
   /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/F18462078E6C9578/debsig.gpg
   ------------------------------------------------------
   pub   rsa4096 2019-07-23 [SC] [expires: 2024-07-21]
         93D5D2A628951B4383D8A4CEF18462078E6C9578
   uid           [ unknown] Slack Packages (Signing Key) <packages@slack-corp.com>
   sig!3        F18462078E6C9578 2019-07-23  Slack Packages (Signing Key) <packages@slack-corp.com>

   gpg: 1 good signature
   ```
5. File `/etc/debsig/policies/F18462078E6C9578/slack.pol` created with the following contents:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE Policy SYSTEM "https://www.debian.org/debsig/1.0/policy.dtd">
   <Policy xmlns="https://www.debian.org/debsig/1.0/">
     <Origin Name="Slack" id="F18462078E6C9578" Description="Slack"/>
     <Selection>
       <Required Type="origin" File="debsig.gpg" id="F18462078E6C9578"/>
     </Selection>
     <Verification>
       <Required Type="origin" File="debsig.gpg" id="F18462078E6C9578"/>
     </Verification>
   </Policy>
   ```

   Note that for the URLs I use `https` rather than the `http` suggested by the slack howto, following the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858700/ (otherwise I also get an error).  Note that this way the `Policy` URL also matches the `Signature Namespace` produced by `debsig-verify --version` in step 1. above.

Unfortunately, the final step fails:

```
# debsig-verify -v -d slack-desktop-4.1.2-amd64.deb
debsig: Starting verification for: slack-desktop-4.1.2-amd64.deb
debsig:         getSigKeyID: got F18462078E6C9578 for origin key
debsig: Using policy directory: /etc/debsig/policies/F18462078E6C9578
debsig:   Parsing policy file: /etc/debsig/policies/F18462078E6C9578/slack.pol
debsig:     parsePolicyFile: parsing '/etc/debsig/policies/F18462078E6C9578/slack.pol'
debsig:     parsePolicyFile: completed
debsig:     Checking Selection group(s).
debsig:       Processing 'origin' key...
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error
debsig: getKeyID subprocess returned error exit status 2
```

### Alternative method?

If I unpack and repack the contents of the `.deb` package without the detached signature, I think I can successfuly verify it:

```
# ar xv slack-desktop-4.1.2-amd64.deb 
x - debian-binary
x - control.tar.gz
x - data.tar.xz
x - _gpgorigin
#
# cat debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.xz > combined
#
# gpg --no-default-keyring \
> --keyring /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/F18462078E6C9578/debsig.gpg \
> --verify _gpgorigin combined
gpg: Signature made Fri 25 Oct 2019 02:47:26 CEST
gpg:                using RSA key F18462078E6C9578
gpg: Good signature from "Slack Packages (Signing Key) <packages@slack-corp.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 93D5 D2A6 2895 1B43 83D8  A4CE F184 6207 8E6C 9578
```

### Questions

My questions are:

- Is the output of the last command enough to consider that the `.deb` package has been verified?
- What should I do differently to make `debsig-verify` work?

Comment: I'm having this same issue when trying to sign packages with Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian 10. I have been able to sign and verify packages with these same steps but on an old Debian Jessie system (have not tested versions inbetween). Perhaps it has to do with GPG versions (v1 to v2). [This wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/GnuPG/UsingGnuPGv2?highlight=%28debsig%29) may provide useful information regarding this. If I figure it out myself I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens when debsig-verify calls `gpg --list-packets /path/to/debsig.gpg`. Possibly to verify if the specified key is contained in debsig.gpg and maybe to check if not other keys are present.

Unfortunately --list-packets is an unsupported debugging command that does not work for the new keybox format keyring files. Thus producing the above error message.

If you can manage to generate your debsig.gpg in e.g. the old keyring v4 format, everything should be fine.
Beyond that it seems we have to hope for an bugfix to debsig-verify.

Unfortunately there is no option to make gpg2 use the old keyring format, but there is a trick. If the keyring file exists and is in the old format, gpg2 will continue using that format. An empty file is detected as the old format. Basically you have to touch your debsig.gpg first before creating it.

Thus, I managed to successfully use `debsig-verify` with `debsig.gpg`'s created with these commands:

```
rm -f /path/to/debsig.gpg
## trick gpg2 into using old keyring format
touch /path/to/debsig.gpg
gpg2 --no-default-keyring \
      --keyring /path/to/debsig.gpg \
      --import signing-pubkey.gpg
```

Comment: Thank you, the strategy you suggested worked - and actually slack updated their website to include it.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was posted on StackOverflow and there was one suggestion that also worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

> This will cause the error
>
> $ gpg --no-default-keyring 
> --keyring /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/DDDF2F4CE732A79A/debsig.gpg 
> --import
>
> This will work
>
> $ cp  /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/DDDF2F4CE732A79A/debsig.gpg

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61014204/2916936

Answer (score 0):

this is due to the fact that https://slack.com/gpg/slack_pubkey_2019.gpg was generated with gpg v1, you can try the following with gpg v2

1. import the v1 key (https://slack.com/gpg/slack_pubkey_2019.gpg)
2. export the same key with gpg2
3. delete-key on the v1 key
4. import the key exported with gpg2